# Limit number of items per line in gdb's x examine memory output

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

Using the e**X**amine command in gdb I get a printout such as the following:

```
>>> x/4c $rbp-8
0x7fffffffe438: 74 'J'  111 'o' 104 'h' 110 'n'
```

Is there a setting where I can specify I only want one character per line? For example, I want the output to look as follows:

```
>>> x/4c $rbp-8
0x7fffffffe438: 74  'J'
0x7fffffffe439: 111 'o'
0x7fffffffe43A: 104 'h'
0x7fffffffe43B: 110 'n'
```

In searching I've seen a few things with the `print` command but nothing really with formatting the `x` command.

Comment: Don't think that is supported. You can write a script if you want.